# jquery editable GUI textbox

Tags: jquery, user-interface, text, textbox

Does anyone know of an jQuery (or anything) plugin that would allow for me to have an editable, GUI-like textbox that would allow my users to edit their text with things such as font, color, bold, or html, etc. I have been searching with no luck. I'm looking for something like ebay's description box when you're listing an item.

Comment: It's called a **Rich Text Editor**. Google will help you from here, young padawan.

Comment: ahh, I see. That is a much better name than my search "fancy text box". lol. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If Google was smarter I think nobody would be asking questions here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jWysiwyg Editor

http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/

Or try TinyMCE. It's great!

you find the jQuery integration Plugin [here](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could take a look at CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com/

Personally, I like that one better than TinyEMC. Tiny can be a bit slow sometimes, and I've had some problems with visitors using an older version of IE (the editor works, just really slow).